# Please help me with VHDL compile error

Tags: compilation, vhdl

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity doorlock is
port(   reset : in std_logic;
    enable : in std_logic;
    password : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    door : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
    lock : out std_logic;
    alarm : out std_logic;
    turnoff : out std_logic);
end doorlock;

--password is 10(decimal no.) which is 00010000(binary no.)

architecture DDL of doorlock is
signal err_count : integer range 0 to 5 := 0;

begin
lock <= '0' when (reset = '0');
alarm <= '0' when (reset = '0');
turnoff <= '0' when (reset = '0');
door <= "00000000" when (reset = '0');
lock <= '0' when (enable <= '0');

process(password)
begin
    if (password = "-------1") then
    door <= "00000000";
    elsif (password = "------10") then
    door <= "00000001";
    elsif (password = "-----100") then
    door <= "00000011";
    elsif (password = "----1000") then
    door <= "00000111";
    elsif (password = "---00000") then
    door <= "00001111";
    elsif (password = "--110000") then
    door <= "00011111";
    elsif (password = "-1010000") then
    door <= "00111111";
    elsif (password = "10010000") then
    door <= "01111111";
    elsif (password = "00010000") then
    door <= "11111111";
    end if;

    err_count <= err_count + 1;
end process;

alarm <= '1' when (err_count = 3);
turnoff <= '1' when (err_count = 5);
lock <= '1' when (door = "11111111" and turnoff = '0' and alarm = '0');

end DDL;
```

I made this code for my homework making digital door lock.
And this line have error as I compile it.

```
lock <= '1' when (door = "11111111" and turnoff = '0' and alarm = '0');
```

Error is like this below

** Error: D:\modelsim\Door.vhd(53): Cannot read output "alarm".

VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.
This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.

** Error: D:\modelsim\Door.vhd(53): Cannot read output "door".

VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.
This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.

** Error: D:\modelsim\Door.vhd(53): Cannot read output "turnoff".

VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs.
This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008.

** Error: D:\modelsim\Door.vhd(55): VHDL Compiler exiting

I don't know why it happens please help me

Comment: The error message tells the whole story: an output port goes out of your module an cannot be read. You can only read input ports and signals. Either you define internal signals for `door`, `alarm` and `turnoff` and assign them to output ports, or you use VHDL-2008, which allows reading of output ports.

Comment: Set your compiler to VHDL-2008 mode, or start using intermediate signals.

Comment: P.s. if you're going to use VHDL-2008, consider using the `case?` statement instead of this if-elsif-elsif-etc. structure.

Comment: Oh, AND you have multiple drivers for your signals. Please consider using a clock and putting all assignments in one process.

Comment: @JHBonarius you just wrote whole answer in your comments. Why didn't you write an answer from them?

Comment: @Staszek I can do in a short while. Writing from my phone now (traveling), not able to write good quality answer.

Comment: The evaluation the metalogical value '-' (IEEE Std 1076-2008, 16.8.2.2 The STD_LOGIC_1164 values) depends on the use of one of IEEE package numeric_std function STD_MATCH, matching relational operators (9.2.3 Relational operators), or matching case statement (10.9 Case statement, which the answer shows) to evaluate the '-' as a don't care (new to -2008, also see 16.8.2.4.4, 16.8.2.4.5 and 16.8.3 ). Unregistered err_count <= err_count + 1 would be a relaxation oscillator in silicon (at least one bit flips, there's delay based on routing and logic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off: "Please help me" is not a good question. Better would be something like "Modelsim error "cannot read output" when compiling"

Second off: The error is quite descriptive. "Cannot read output "alarm"". `alarm` is declared as

```
alarm : out std_logic;
```

Thus it is an **output** port. In pre-2008 VHDL it was not allowed to read output ports. Next the compiler hints on how to fix it:

> "VHDL 2008 allows reading outputs. This facility is enabled by compiling with -2008."

So do so!
In your modelsim compilation window select "default options"

[image]

And then set to VHDL-2008

[image]

Alternatively you can actually do what is described (add the `-2008`) on the command line:

> vcom -reportprogress 300 -work work -2008 doorlock.vhd

Voila. Finished! Not?

---

### No wait, still doesn't work!

You have a multiple driver error. In line 23 it states:

```
door <= "00000000" when (reset = '0');
```

This acts as a latch, effectively being the same as

```
process(reset) begin
    if reset = '0' then
        door <= "00000000";
    end if;
end process;
```

Thus once `reset='0'` has occurred, the process will drive `door` to a fixed value. In the `password`-triggered process you again drive `door`! This will resolve badly. E.g. if `(password = "------10")`, then `door <= "00000001"`. This will resolve:

```
resolve("00000000", "00000001") = "0000000X"
```

Because connecting `'0'` to `'1'` is equivalently a short-circuit.

So let's look at proper design. You're now triggering on a change of `password`. Not so nice, but it's possible. I would use another trigger, like the `enable` signal that is not being used. But anyhow: we introduce an extra signal to detect the change `password_delay`. But more importantly **we introduce a clock**. In digital hardware most systems use a clock. Finally, we use the new VHDL-2008 statement `case?` to decode the don't cares.

Together the VHDL-2008 code becomes:

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

entity doorlock is
    port(
        clk : in std_logic;
        reset : in std_logic;
        enable : in std_logic;
        password : in std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        door : out std_logic_vector (7 downto 0);
        lock : out std_logic;
        alarm : out std_logic;
        turnoff : out std_logic
        );
end doorlock;

--password is 10(decimal no.) which is 00010000(binary no.)

architecture DDL of doorlock is
    signal password_delay : std_logic_vector(password'range) := password;
    use ieee.numeric_std_unsigned.all;
    signal err_count : integer range 0 to 5 := 0;
begin
    clk_proc : process(clk) begin
        if rising_edge(clk) then
            if reset = '0' then
                door <= (others => '0');
                lock <= '0';
                alarm <= '0';
                turnoff <= '0';
                err_count <= 0;
            else -- no reset :)
                if password /= password_delay then
                    case? password is
                        when "-------1" => door <= "00000000";
                        when "------10" => door <= "00000001";
                        when "-----100" => door <= "00000011";
                        when "----1000" => door <= "00000111";
                        when "---00000" => door <= "00001111";
                        when "--110000" => door <= "00011111";
                        when "-1010000" => door <= "00111111";
                        when "10010000" => door <= "01111111";
                        when "00010000" => door <= "11111111";
                        when others => null;
                    end case?;
                    err_count <= err_count + 1;
                end if;
                case err_count is
                    when 3 => alarm <= '1';
                    when 5 => turnoff <= '1';
                    when others => null;
                end case;
                if door = "11111111" and turnoff = '0' and alarm = '0' then
                    lock <= '1';
                end if;
            end if;
            password_delay <= password;
        end if;
    end process;
end DDL;
```

That's something different, eh? I'm sorry, but I don't have time to write a test bench for you.

NOTE: The code gives a compiler warning

> Warning: C:/HDL/doorlock/doorlock.vhd(20): (vcom-1013) Initial value of "password_delay" depends on value of signal "password".

Ignore this. This is required for simulation as else undefined initial value of `password_delay`will cause a trigger of `password /= password_delay`.

Comment: Thank you so much but can I ask you another question? I wrote this code exactly the same and simulated it but outputs weren't changed as I change inputs. 30 mins of lecture in my class about vhdl is not enough to solve this problem ;(

Comment: @JinHoyong studying is much more then 30 min lecture (30 min is very short by the way): it's reading the book, doing exersizes, etc. Using somebody else's code is not studying. I'm a tutor at a university, and if I would see somebody's homework contain code which that person did not know yet, I would ask the student to come explain the code. If he/she cannot, I would fail him/her for the course. So don't use code you cannot explain....